# Mockito verification fails when Mockito.Times is called

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
class Display extends JFrame{
  public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.setIconImage(image);
  }
}
```

Test

```
public class DisplayConfigurationTest {
  @Mock
  private DisplayConfiguration displayMock;

  @Test
  public void setFrame_Icon_shouldSetWindowIcon() throws Exception {        
    displayMock.setImage(null);
    verify(displayMock, times(1)).setIconImage(null);
  }
}
```

Test throws an error :

Wanted but not invoked:
displayMock.setIconImage(null);
-> at DisplayConfigurationTest.setFrame_Icon_shouldSetWindowIcon(DisplayConfigurationTest.java)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
displayMock.setImage(null);
-> DisplayConfigurationTest.setFrame_Icon_shouldSetWindowIcon(DisplayConfigurationTest.java)

Comment: You're verifying `setIconImage`, whereas you're calling `setImage`.

Comment: I want to verify whether setIconImage() which is inside is called..should I use a spy then ?

Answer (score 0):

When you `@Mock` an object, that object's methods effectively stop working. You can then tell the mock what should happen when any of the methods are called (including `callRealMethod()`). So in your example, you could check if `setImage()` was called 1 time, but `setIconImage()` will not be called.

What you actually want is a *real*  `Display` (or `DisplayConfiguration` - it's not clear from your code), in which all member objects are `@Mock`ed.

Alternatively, in the current code, you could add this as the first line of your test method:

```
when(displayMock.setImage(any())).thenCallRealMethod();
```